# Publish a Spring Boot Project as a library in maven repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I have a Spring Boot Project which has a repository over BitBucket. This is a Gradle project. Now *I want to publish my repository in maven repository so that I can use it into my other projects*. I'm new with publishing projects. **What could be the possible guidelines for this?**

Comment: Spring Boot itself is now built using Gradle. I would suggest starting by looking at their code to see how they generate POMs for publishing.

Comment: [gradle maven publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to use your artifacts for your own projects and you don't want to distribute them so other people can use them in their projects, you can use an [internal repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#internal-repositories) (maven-only). If you want to share your work with the entire world, the Maven site has [a guide](https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html) about how to upload to Maven Central (maven-only).

EDIT: Since you're using gradle, [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:declaring_custom_repository) is how you use internal repositories. And [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) is how you publish to a repository, like Maven Central.

Comment: But what for **Gradle** Project? As it doesn't have any POM.xml?

Comment: See the edit I made to my answer. Gradle too offers similar procedures, I included links to the equivalent Gradle documentation/tutorials.

Comment: The links themselves work fine for me. Or do you mean the procedure described in the documentation is not giving you the expected results? Note that I'm linking the official gradle documentation for the most recent version of gradle.

Comment: Don't know, gradle links are not working for me but maven links are working.